# Joomla not showing the correct page

Tags: joomla

So I have several sites using Joomla. The currently installed Joomla version is "‎4.3.4". I have set the URL rewriting and the .htaccess file. yet it still ONLY shows the index page. I have verified that the pages exist, and it shows the correct URL in the browser bar, but DOES not show the actual page. Suggestions? because at this point I'm stumped.

Updated PHP, Updated Joomla Version. verified pages exist within admin, changed the .htaccess file from htaccess.txt, set URL rewriting, cleared cache, rebooted the server...swore at it.....a lot.

expectation: when I click on a link it displays THAT page rather than reload the home page

Comment: Do you see any errors in the php logs? If you set the default template, does the error still appear?